# async.series not working as expected Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
var myFunction = function (param1,cb) {
    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            func1(param1,callback);//An error occurred here. I pass error to callback.
        },
        function(callback) {
            func2(param1,callback);
        },
        function(callback) {
            func3(callback);
        }
    ],function(err, results) {  //Its called immediately when error occurred in any of the above function, but the remaining function also keeps on executing in parallel.
        if (typeof cb === "function") {
            cb(err,results);
        }
});
};
```

If an error occurred during func1, I pass the error to the callback.

The callback of async.series called immediately when error occurred in any of the above function, but the remaining function also keeps on executing in parallel.

I don't want the other functions to execute if an error occured in any function.

Comment: Are you sure, your callback in func1 or in func2 is not called twice ?

Comment: thanks, that was the mistake.

Comment: I was not returning the callback. I was just calling it. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use waterfall for  expected result.

```
var myFunction = function (param1,cb) {
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
            callback(param1);
        }
    function(param1 ,callback) {
        callback(param1);
    },
    function(param1 , callback) {

        callback(null, 'result');
    }
], function (err, result) {
     if (typeof cb === "function") {
            cb(err,results);
        }
});
}
```